# Storing open hours for a site in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp-with-timezone

I am trying to store on Postgres site opening hours, after reading this [link](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/310557/storing-hours-a-merchant-is-open-in-postgres) I managed to come up with this table

```
create table opening_hours 
 (
    store_id  int REFERENCES site (id) NOT NULL,
    day_of_the_week integer NOT NULL,
    open_time    time with time zone not NULL,
    close_time   time with time zone not NULL
);
```

I am having a problem now that some stores are open between 6 AM and 1 AM on the following day.

As the `time` field is limited to `24:00:00` I could add a new row to the same table for the remaining hours e.g:

```
store_id,day_of_the_week,open_time,close_time
1,0,'06:00:00','24:00:00'
1,1,'00:00:00','01:00:00'
1,1,'06:00:00','24:00:00'
...
```

But that just seems to be too convoluted.

Another solution is to create this table:

```
create table opening_hours 
 (
    store_id  int REFERENCES site (id) NOT NULL,
    day_of_the_week integer NOT NULL,
    open_time    time with time zone not NULL,
    operating_minutes   integer not NULL
);
```

and populate the table with such content:

```
store_id,day_of_the_week,open_time,operating_minutes
1,0,'06:00:00',500
1,1,'06:00:00',500
...
```

However, this query would make the query to determine if a store is `now()` open a bit more difficult as I would need to consider specific cases when querying, ultimately what I would like to query is:

```
select (localtime > open_time and localtime < close_time) from opening_hours oh  where store_id = 1 and day_of_the_week = date_part('dow', now())
```

Another thing that I was considering is that I am always storing data for every store no matter if they are open or not, but for some of the reports, I need to filter out the events within the time range defined on my table `opening_hours`.

I'm looking for advice on what would be the preferred way of storing this data into Postgres.

Comment: [Don't use time with time zone](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_timetz)

Comment: Are stores closing at lunchtime giving you two intervals for one day of the week a relevant use case here? Maybe having multiple intervals (rows) on one weekday would also help for stores remaining open over midnight?

Comment: You can probably use a query like `select (now() between current_date() + open_time and current_date() + open_time + interval '1 minute' * operating_minutes) from opening_hours oh  where store_id = 1 and day_of_the_week = date_part('dow', now())`

Answer (score 1):

You can query for an open store with this logic:

```
where (open_time < close_time and localtime between open_time and close_time) or
      (open_time > close_time and localtime not between open_time and close_time)
```

This uses `between` and `not between` for simplicity.  However, they may not handle the exact opening and closing times the way you want (are those specific times included or not?).